# Angular2 Why are all my routes throwing 404s?

Tags: angular

**In my simple NG2 SPA, everything I navigate to throws a 404 except "/"**

index.html (excerpted)

```
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="/">
    <!-- lots of script tags -->
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.config({
        packages: {app: {format: 'register',defaultExtension: 'js'}}
      });
      System.import('app/main')
        .catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <my-foo>Loading...</my-foo>
  </body>
</html>
```

app/main.ts

```ts
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

app/app.module.ts

```ts
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MeetingComponent } from './meeting.component';
import { routing } from './app.router';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, routing ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, MeetingComponent ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app/app.component.ts

```ts
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { MeetingComponent } from './meeting.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-foo',
  template: `
  <h1>Hello World</h1>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

app/app.router.ts

```ts
import { RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
import { MeetingComponent } from './meeting.component';

export const routes = [
  {path:"", component: MeetingComponent},
  {path:"foo", component: MeetingComponent},
  {path:"meeting", component: MeetingComponent}
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

meeting.component.ts

```ts
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';    

@Component({
  selector: 'my-meeting',
  template: `<div>I'm the meeting component</div>`
}) 
export class MeetingComponent {}
```

Now I should be able to navigate to localhost:3000, localhost:3000/foo, or localhost:3000/meeting and all get to the same thing. But only localhost:3000 shows up. The other URLs are throwing 404s

For the love of $DEITY ... why?!?

Comment: Did you try moving `path:""` to bottom?

Comment: @SefaÜmitOray I don't think that will help.

Comment: @SefaÜmitOray I tried. It made no difference. Thanks, though.

Comment: what is the exact error msg?

Comment: How are you 'serving' your app? Which Webserver? or with `ng serve` ?

Comment: @micronyks No error message at all. Just 404 from the server.

Comment: @mxii Node with Express is my web server.

Comment: Your Webserver needs to know those routes too! It tries to search '/foo' and dont know what to do.. so there are 2 ways: 1. Webserver needs to route all routes to '/' without changing the url. 2. use angular's hashbang feature

Comment: @mxii Yep. That was it. If you post it as an answer I'll accept it. If not, I'll answer it myself with what I did to fix it. Thanks very much.

Comment: Yw. I guess you can put more details in that answer, but thanks! :)